# Does the following actually violate the ODR?

Tags: c++, static, inline, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

From [here](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4147.pdf):

> ```
> struct piecewise_construct_t {};
> constexpr piecewise_construct_t piecewise_construct = {};
>
> const int magic_number = 42;
>
> inline std::tuple<int> make_magic() {
> return std::tuple<int>( piecewise_construct, magic_number );
> }
> ```
>
> This function violates the ODR ([basic.def.odr] §3.2/6 ) twice because
>   neither of the constructor 2 arguments receives an lvalue-to-rvalue
>   conversion. They are therefore passed by address, but the address
>   depends on the TU because const (and constexpr) implies internal
>   linkage.

I initially thought it did, but the problem is that `magic_number` has internal linkage. Since it has internal linkage, wouldn't it essentially treat `magic_number` as if they were different variables in different translation units, and therefore not as multiple definitions of the same variable? Can someone specify this by using quotes of the latest working draft of the C++ standard?

Comment: I think the good @potatoswatter (David Krauss) is simply very wrong here. Also the statement "There is no way to share a compile-time constant between TUs unless it is scalar and every use is 
discarded or undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion." ignores the template constant technique. Which *should* be mentioned in such a paper to show that the necessary machinery for `inline` for data, already is in place.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's possible he was referring to an older version of the standard or I just misinterpreted what he wrote, but just to clarify, the above example does not actually violate the ODR rule correct? I couldn't seem to find anything relating linkage and definitions even though it should seem obvious that any variable with internal linkage should not have any conflicts with another variable (even of the same name) with internal linkage in a different translation unit.

Comment: I see from [T.C.s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31644046/464581) that I misinterpreted the quote. I read it as applying to use of the constant, when it was really about an `inline` function having different definitions. It's pretty subtle.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Completely my fault. My little blurb after the quote from the paper was really my misinterpretation and probably influenced how you read it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with `make_magic`. [basic.def.odr]/p6:

> There can be more than one definition of ... inline function with
>   external linkage (7.1.2) ... in a program provided that each
>   definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the
>   definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity
>   named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
> - in each definition of `D`, corresponding names, looked up according to 3.4, shall refer to an entity defined within the definition of `D`, or shall refer to the same entity, after overload resolution (13.3) and
>     after matching of partial template specialization (14.8.3), except
>     that a name can refer to a non-volatile `const` object with internal or
>     no linkage if the object has the same literal type in all definitions
>     of `D`, and the object is initialized with a constant expression (5.20),
>     and the object is not odr-used, and the object has the same value in
>     all definitions of `D`; and
> - [...]

Because `piecewise_construct` and `magic_number` have internal linkage, when the inline function `make_magic` is defined in multiple translation units, the names `piecewise_construct` and `magic_number` refer to different entities - TU 1's `make_magic` will refer to TU 1's `piecewise_construct` and `magic_number`, and TU 2's `make_magic` will refer to TU 2's `piecewise_construct` and `magic_number`. Since the constructor of `tuple` at issue takes the arguments by reference, no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is performed, the objects are odr-used, and the exception in the second bullet doesn't apply, and you have an ODR violation.

(Incidentally, `std::tuple` doesn't have a `piecewise_construct` constructor, and in any event such a constructor would presumably take tuples as arguments rather than a plain `int`, but that's orthogonal to the point the paper is trying to make.)

Comment: Ah! I misinterpreted what he wrote. So if you were to write a non-inline function in a source file that odr-uses `magic_number` (i.e. takes an `int` by reference) and is called by separate translation units there wouldn't be an issue correct? My initial reasoning was that odr-use of `magic_number` in different translation units was an issue because it has multiple definitions, but since the linkage is internal it is essentially treated as different variables between translation units (i.e. could you even go so far as to give it separate values in different translation units?).

Comment: @jucestain If the function is not inline (so defined only in one TU) then it's fine. " since the linkage is internal it is essentially treated as different variables between translation units (i.e. could you even go so far as to give it separate values in different translation units?)" That's correct, and you can.

Comment: That seems SO weird, but clarifies some preconceived misconceptions I had.